# How to get index of list in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, checkboxlist

i am having foreach loop on ChekboxList like

```
foreach (ListItem li in chkUnitCategory.Items)
{
}
```

now i need to perform a task in which when checkbox of index 0 is selected all the other checkbox in list must be selected and vice versa.

so how can i perform this task using index of check box list.

Comment: You have two upvoted answers to your question. If any of them answers your question in a satisfactory way you should mark it as an accepted answer (grey checkbox). Doing this will help others, with the same question as yours, to see what is an acceptable answer and also to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a note changing collection is not allowed when you iterating over it.

If you need, try:

```
foreach (ListItem li in chkUnitCategory.Items)
{
   li.Selected = chkUnitCategory.Items[0].Selected;
}
```

Comment: You can modify an item, just not remove  or add items to the collection

Comment: actually item was my mistake, its collection. thanks for pointing :)

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkUnitCategory.Items.Count; i++)
{
  chkUnitCategory.Items[i].Selected = chkUnitCategory.Items[0].Selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would write it utilizing LINQ:

```
chkUnitCategory.Items.ForEach(item => item.Selected = chkUnitCategory.Items.First().Selected)
```